# Create Matrix Of Row

Tags: c++, matrix, data-structures, c++14, stdvector

I have a vector like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

How would I make it so it prints out a matrix or returns it into a row like this:

```
{
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
}
```

I have a function that creates a matrix that takes a vector as an argument.

How would I get it so it makes like this:

```
{
{1}
{2}
{3}
{4}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see *how* have you implemented that *matrix* and what do you mean by "vector".

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure to understand what you want.

But since the comment zone is too short, I guess while answering.

If what you want is to print exactly what you've shown from the data... which I think is a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vct {1, 2, 3, 4};

    std::cout << "{\n";
    for (auto elem : vct)
        std::cout << "{" << elem << "}\n";

    std::cout << "}\n";

    return 0;
}
```